# Convert Different Format documents into 1 bit png files in .net

Tags: c#, .net, png, tiff

Hi I have an initiative of converting bunch of different formats such as Word, PDF, png, jpg, excel files into '1 bit png' files and store them in the database.

I need to use .net framework for this. Do you guys know any tools that can do this, I want some tools or API that I can buy. I am pretty sure I would need more than one tool for doing this, which is fine.

What would be the best way to do this? It is possible to convert them all to TIFF format and then convert them to png?

Thanks

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?  That is, why would you need to store a .docx (for example) as a 1-bit png in a database of any sort?  There may be an easier way to solve your bigger problem.

Comment: Wait, you want to store a Word doc, as a black & white PNG, in a database field, using .NET?! I'd love to know the reasons why! Next up: creating HTML from MIDI files stored on floppies using JavaScript.

Comment: Well those are the requirements that I got from the architect. They want to use as less memory as possible on the server. So they want me to convert all types of documents into .png Grayscale or 1 bit. When the user wants to access those files, they will be converted to .pdf files and will be shown to the user.

What would be the best way to do this? I think space is one of their main issues. They want this conversion to be done in 900ms. They don't want to use open source software either, it needs to be something that we can buy : \

Comment: I'm sure the creators of Ghostscript and ImageMagick would be happy to take your money in exchange for their products.

Comment: That list of requirements is absolutely pathological.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to a duplicate of [Is there a programming toolkit for converting “any file type” to a TIFF image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594613/is-there-a-programming-toolkit-for-converting-any-file-type-to-a-tiff-image).  I'll just repeat what I wrote at that time:

---

This is an integration project - there is no one tool that will read all of the file types you're interested in.  In our case, we developed a generic transcoding service that accepts numerous input types (by file extension) and executes external applications based on that type:

- [Ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594613/is-there-a-programming-toolkit-for-converting-any-file-type-to-a-tiff-image) for PDF and PS files,
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for image files,
- [Apose.NET](http://www.aspose.com/) for Office types, and
- some homegrown stuff for simpler types like text files.

We haven't found an application that will interpret Visio files of all versions other than Visio itself.  And as you may already know, Office Interop [should not be used on a server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).